# Python; class instances

Tags: python, class

Suppose I have a class, call it `class1,` with 3 class variables `var1,var2,var3,` and  `__init__`   method, which assigns passed arguments to the class variables:

```
class class1(object):
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 0
    var3 = 0

    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
       class1.var1 = a
       class1.var2 = b
       class1.var3 = c
```

Now I'm going to make two instances of the same class:

```
obj1 = class1(1,2,3)
obj2 = class1(4,5,6)
```

And now, let's take a look at variables values:

```
print (obj1.var1, obj1.var2,obj1.var3)
4 5 6
print (obj2.var1, obj2.var2,obj2.var3)
4 5 6
```

Shouldn't `obj1` have values 1,2,3 ?  Why `__init__` method of the second instance changes vaues in the first instance(`obj1`)? And how to make two independent separate instances of a class?

Comment: You have *specifically* made these class, not instance, attributes. If you want instance attributes, use e.g. `self.var1 = a`, and remove the assignments outside `__init__`.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Variables declared in the class definition, but *not inside a method*, will be **class variables**. In other words, they will be the same for the whole class.

To solve this you could declare them in the `__init__` method, so they become **instance variables**:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.var1 = a
        self.var2 = b
        self.var3 = c
```

Answer (score 2):

Class variables are shared by all instances of the class (and the class itself). You need to use instance variables instead.

```
>>> class class1(object):
...     def __init__(self,a,b,c):
...        self.var1 = a
...        self.var2 = b
...        self.var3 = c
...
>>> obj1 = class1(1,2,3)
>>> obj2 = class1(4,5,6)
>>> print (obj1.var1, obj1.var2,obj1.var3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> print (obj2.var1, obj2.var2,obj2.var3)
(4, 5, 6)
```